# Python regex match until character over multiple lines

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, newline

I have a file formatted like this:

```
hello = {

     a = "2354a"
     b = "06567567h"


}

goodbye = {
     there = "/home/afhge"

}

...

anotherset = {
      dsfsdf = grhbrwecs
      dfgtmyj = 12345

}
```

I am using regular expressions in python, what I want matched is everything inside the braces so the resulting match output would be the following list:

```
['\n\n\ta = "2345a"\n\tb = "06567567h"\n\n\n', '\n\there = "/home/afhge"\n\n', '\n\tdsfsdf = grhbrwecs\n\tdfgtmyj = 12345\n\n']
```

I have tried the regex:

```
desired_output = re.findall("{[^}]", file_text)
```

however this regex results in the list:

```
['{\n', '{\n', '{\n', '{\n', '{\n']
```

It looks like [^}] matches any character up until a newline. I've tried doing:

```
desired_output = re.findall("{[^}]", file_text, re.S)
```

and

```
desired_output  = re.findall("{[^}]", file_text, re.M)
```

To no success :(.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No your character class is right. It will match any character that is not `}` (even line breaks). The problem is that `[^}]` matches only one character. Simply use a repetition quantifier (and you should probably escape the `{`):

```
r"\{[^}]*"
```

Regarding the options you tried. If anything `re.S` would help, because without it `.` does not match line breaks. But the `.` is really the only thing affected by `re.S`. The other option `re.M` has nothing to with it. That just makes the anchors `^` and `$` match at line beginnings and ends as well.

Also, since you only want the content within the brackets, you don't need to match the `{` itself, but you could use a lookbehind instead:

```
r"(?<=\{)[^}]*"
```

This will not include the `{` in the match.

Comment: Amazing this worked thanks!

As for not including the { in the match I just put brackets around the code I wanted displayed. My new regex:
"\{([^\}]*)"

Comment: @m3hughes yup that's a different possibility.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `(?<={).*?(?=})`

Your regex is **missing** `}` to specify where to end the match and `.*?` which matches 0 to many characters till it matches the first `}`

Comment: Works but I gave the verified to m.buettner's answer because it had more details about re.S and re.M which were helpful.